# how to install a external power switch to my Asus EEE PC HE1000

Tags: netbook, power, switch

i've been using my netbook to source my carputer for a few months now. my only complain is booting up the system whenever I start my car.

I've read articles from other sites like mp3car.com and here as well but no direct way to automatically boot up my netbook externally. I guess I've been in denial all these months that I may find a safer solution, I'm starting to believe I was wrong.

I've also searched the bios if there's a "boot on power" with the Asus, but i found nothing. I also tried the hack where my netbook "wakes" upon LAN, it works, but it'll just heat up my machine while i'm away. My only option is breaking into the netbook and hotwiring the power with a momentary switch.

if there's someone here who have tried hacking their machine (specifically the Asus EEE netbooks) with an external power switch, can anyone guide me to where to start?

My issues are:
- Some hidden switch that disables power up when the netbook is closed (some sort of magnet?)
- Which part of the netbook should I solder or glue?

If you have other suggestions, feel welcome to comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to cut into power circuit which is soldered on a mainboard, there's just no place to hook into some long wire - there are almost no wires in that netbooks.

There is a variety of choices for commuting the power, but remember that:

1) when you turn a key, car's network experiences voltage/current shocks - don't use this as power-on event. Instead, just add a delay circuit with a kind of transistor, which will connect 12 to 19V dc converter to your netbook after a small delay - and solder the power button contacts out to some external control on panel. After all, you have to reboot your machine by a power switch sometimes..

2) if you had to solder any switch (including transistors/relays) into any IC, you can add a capacitor of small value around it's contacts to avoid unnecessary effects; this will also introduce side effects, but is needed sometimes

What you have done already?

Comment: actually, i haven't started on anything yet. there's also a factor of the magnet between the hinges where it disables the netbook to turn-on when the lid is closed. how do i fix that?